# ecryptfs module within WSL not loaded

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ecryptfs

I'm trying to load an ecryptfs encrypted folder on a USB device on Windows with WSL2. I've followed the instructions [here](https://rabbithole.uzver.org/hackery/ecryptfs-on-windows) to build a new linux kernel. However, when I do `modprobe ecryptfs` inside the WSL session I'm still getting

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module ecryptfs not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2+
```

In my home folder there is a `.wslconfig` file which contains

```
[wsl2]
kernel=C:\\Users\\myusername\\linuxkernel\\bzImage
```

and `bzImage` is the build result.
If anyone has an idea what could be the problem I'd be grateful for a hint. In particular, I'd like to know if the image I've built is actually loaded (is there some command from within the WSL session to check?) and whether I can perform some kind of "offline" check on the kernel file to see if it contains the ecryptfs module or not (so basically if the build did what it was supposed to do).

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you do `wsl --shutdown` to make sure the Linux VM is fully stopped, as indicated in the guide?

Comment: Yes, I did.....

Comment: Why would you even need to `modprobe`? Isn't WSL kernel supposed to be all-builtin? Your guide says `CONFIG_ECRYPT_FS=y` (not `=m`) too.

Comment: You could change the `CONFIG_LOCALVERSION` to something else on your build. It will be visible in `uname -a` (or not).